# SignalR 1.0alpha2 Console Server Application

Tags: asp.net, nuget, signalr

I'm playing around with the new 1.0alpha2 release of signalR.
I want to implement a SignalR server outside an ASP.NET application. So that two console applications can talk to each other.

With the old 0.5.3 version I was able to "Install-Package SignalR.Hosting.Self" to:

```
var server = new Server("http://127.0.0.1:8088/");
```

But in the new 1.0alpha2 Release I can't install this NuGet Package...

Can anyone give me a link or maybe a working mini example of two console applications which based on the **1.0alpha2** release. (I can only find not working old 0.5.3 examples...).

---

Ok. so I've followed your instructions. Now:

My Client Console:

```
class Programm 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost/");
    IHubProxy myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
    connection.Start().ContinueWith(task =>
      {
          if (task.IsFaulted)
              Console.WriteLine("No Connection: " + task.Exception.GetBaseException());
          else
              Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
      });

    myHub.Invoke("Send");

    Console.ReadLine(); // wait...
  }
}
```

And here is my Server Console:

```
class Program : Hub
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      Console.ReadKey();
  }
  public void Send(string message)
  {
      Debug.WriteLine("Server Method [send] was called");
      Console.WriteLine("Server Method [send] was called");
  }
}
```

But this is nonsense I think...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the new NuGet package since SignalR went official: (says ASP but its used in .NET applications too)

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -pre` Server

`Install-Package -pre Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` Client

There is also a prebuilt sample application here that you can then hook your console application into for some testing :

`Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Sample`

Using the clients; connecting two console applications one would need to host the hub and other would need to use the client connection pointing to the host.

All of the info that you need is in this client wiki: [link](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-Client-Hubs)

---

***EDIT***

Server: (Using Self Host)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:8081/";
        var server = new Server(url);

        // Map the default hub url (/signalr)
        server.MapHubs();

        // Start the server
        server.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);

        // Keep going until somebody hits 'x'
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo ki = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (ki.Key == ConsoleKey.X)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(message);

        }
    }

}
```

Client:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:8081/");

        IHubProxy proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

        connection.Start().Wait();

        proxy.On("addMessage", data => { Console.WriteLine("From Server: " + data); });

        while (true)
        {
            proxy.Invoke("Send", Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }
}
```

[image]

PS. ill add the downloads to both solutions in the comments below. I'm sure you'll be fine going ahead.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my first post with my new code. But I think I didn't understood how to do it...

Comment: @SaschaVoid - putting together a sample ... give me a few minutes

Comment: Hey f0x: Thanks for your sample. But my Problem is, that I don't have the Server Class. I cannot use var server = new Server(url);

Comment: @SaschaVoid You need an additional reference. Solutions as promised : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/67200967/SignalR%20%28Server%20%2B%20Client%29.zip

Comment: Ah! You mean "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Self.dll". Can you tell me how to get this assembly? I've tried several times to install it via Install-Package but it doesn't work. I've copied the assembly from your working project in mine, but still the same confusing issue. But your solution works. I'll try it at night, thank you very very much for your help!

Comment: @SaschaVoid thats the only way to get it at the moment, building the source. glad it works, please mark the question answered at the top! thanks!

Comment: @SaschaVoid - I ran into the same problem. I was told that they were redoing the self-hosting for the release, but in the meantime, you can get the Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hosting.Self.dll by building the source yourself. The main downside to that is that I then needed to replace all references to the DLLs from NuGet, as they seem to need the exact same version of the DLLs all the way through the solution.

Comment: Yes you're right. I also replaced all NuGet assemblys with the one from f0x and now it works. @f0x: Thank you! I marked your answer as the right one

Comment: @SaschaVoid cheers! good luck! keep an eye out for when self host and owin merge in the future.

Comment: @f0x yeah, now I'm following David Fowler on Twitter to get the latest news around SignalR.